# How to check if number is not a string without using parseInt?

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATE:

Found solution:

```
isNaN(your_number)
```

Comment: Convert it to an array of what? Why do you need this?

Comment: Need more information. Such as how the desired output should look.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have some delimiter such as a comma in the string telling you where each array element ends and the next begins. If that is the case you can split it using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Then you can [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the resulting array to JSON:

```
var somestring = 'blah,bleh,foo,bar,hah!';
var json = JSON.stringify(somestring.split(','))
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

`var temp  = [$('#myID option:selected').val()];`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to put the single string value in an array, you could do it this way:

```
var yourArray = [$('#myID').val()];
```

> 'if I dont select anything from select box in form, then it should
>   return an empty array, instead of a null value'

If I understand your statement correctly, you want an empty array when there is no value selected and you want an array that contains the value otherwise. You could achieve this by doing:

```
var v = $('#myID').val(),
    yourArray = v !== null? [v] : [];
```

You could then convert your array to JSON using `JSON.stringify`

```
var json = JSON.stringify(yourArray);`
```

Comment: Tried it. The condition is, if I dont select anything from select box in form, then it should return an empty array, instead of a null value. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but you can try this:

```
var temp = new Array();
temp.push($('#myID').val());
```

BTW, for selects by using the method val() you actually get the option selected.

you can also try:

```
var temp = [$('#myID').val()];
```

This initializes your variable temp as an array by assigning the value in [].

Comment: `var temp = [];` seems pretty to me

Comment: I need to get selected value from form, which return a single value which is string. I just need to return it as array. Like "string" to ["string"].

Comment: exactly now temp is an array, try temp[0] and you will see that it will return the value you added.